# Blender 2.5 Python find uv layer image

Tags: python, blender

I have a mesh in blender with one uv layer that is mapped to an image. From python I want to access the properties of that image (for example name, width and height).

I can get the uv layer like this:

```
ob = context.active_object
me = ob.data
uv_layer = me.uv_textures[0]

# does not work:
img = uv_layer.image
```

In blender 2.4x it was possible to do this:
    img = me.faces[0].image

How can I access the image object in Blender 2.5 ?

Comment: In the documentation: http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_59_release/bpy.types.MeshTextureFaceLayer.html 

there is a data object, how can I see what it contains?

Comment: you can see what the object has using dir(object)

Comment: tried dir(me.uv_textures[0].data) but there is no output in the console

Comment: use type() to see what type data is

Comment: Ok, found out how to do it:

img = me.uv_textures[0].data.values()[0].image

ps: had to use print(dir(obj))

Comment: posted as comment because "I'm not able to answer my own question for another 7 hours"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found out how to do it:

```
img = me.uv_textures[0].data.values()[0].image
```